# chunked encoding: is there a way to stop the browser spinner before the last chunk?

Tags: http, firefox, google-chrome, safari, chunked-encoding

i'm using chunked encoding to send down an http response. i'd like the browser spinner to go away (signal that the page is done loading) before the last chunk is sent down.

is there any possible way to do this? the content of the next chunk doesn't seem to matter. i even tried sending a chunk that closes the  body but the spinner keeps going after that. i tried this in all major browsers.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Javascript (Ajax) request instead of chunked encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to your chunked-response URL using `setTimeout`:

```
  window.setTimeout(function () {
      doConnect();
  }, 0);
```